# How to import parent template except for its overriden content in django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to extend two nested blocks from a parent template in a child template.

It goes like this :

parent.html

```
{% block parentBlock %}
    <span> Foo </span>
    {% block rowBlock %}
        <button ...> Button here </button>
        <button ...> Another button here </button>
    {% endblock rowBlock %}
    
    <div> Some other content </div>
{% endblock parentBlock %}
```

child.html

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

{% block parentBlock %}
    {{ block.super }} # --> See note n°1 below
    {% block rowBlock %}
        {{ block.super }}
        <button ...> A third button that extends the 2 others </button>
    {% endblock rowBlock %}

    <div> Content that extends parentBlock from parent.html </div>
{% endblock parentBlock %}
```

**Note n° 1**: Problem is that the child's block.super on parentBlock marked as Note 1 will do a super that includes the new rowBlock and appends the new one one more.

Result is like this :

```
<span> Foo </span>
<button ...> Button here </button>
<button ...> Another button here </button>
<button ...> A third button that extends the 2 others </button>
<button ...> Button here </button>
<button ...> Another button here </button>
<button ...> A third button that extends the 2 others </button>
<div> Some other content </div>
<div> Content that extends parentBlock from parent.html </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, as I was writing my question, I tested a new layout for the child.html that solved the issue :

child.html

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

{% block rowBlock %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <button ...> A third button that extends the 2 others </button>
{% endblock rowBlock %}

{% block parentBlock %}
    {{ block.super }}
    # Pulled the nested block outside of parent, it is computed in block.super

    <div> Content that extends parentBlock from parent.html </div>
{% endblock parentBlock %}
```

So pulling the child out if its parent allows the parent to compute the child and display it, but it doesn't affect the order of appearance of the elements.